# Is there an easy way to reverse the ordering of a scale inside an aes() inside a geom()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've found many examples describing the assignment of alpha when in a ggplot2 line like so:

```
scale_alpha( variable, trans = reverse)
```

[ref](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/alpha)

However, is there a method to simply invert the scale in `aes()` inside the `geom_*()`?

Something like:

```
geom_point(aes(colour=variableA, alpha=REVERSE(variableB))
```

Comment: `geom_point(aes(colour=variableA, alpha=-variableB)`? But you might want to modify the scale labels then.

Comment: You could also try function `rev` instead of `REVERSE`.

Comment: @Roland, that was the frustration with that. I was just trying to find the simplest way to reverse the scale in that call without effectively making the values negative.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, embarrassingly, I had actually written the above in the intent of pseudo code. I hadn't actually discovered rev()! I had found reverse_trans(), but that didn't suit this.

Comment: You have probably noticed: `rev(variableB)` is not what you want. For each point, you're getting the alpha value from another row from the data this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to reverse the scale by which `alpha` is assigned inside a `geom`...?

For example, by default lower values of `x` will have lower values of `alpha`, and appear lighter:

```
# sample data
tibble(
  x = 1:10,
  y = 1,
) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, alpha = x))+
  geom_point(size = 5)
```

[image]

You can reverse it so lower values of `x` are darker, by using `sort()` inside `aes()`:

```
tibble(
  x = 1:10,
  y = 1,
) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, alpha = sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)))+
  geom_point(size = 5)
```

[image]

Edit: just realised the legend is incorrect. I guess it's ok if you don't include the legend.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as correct, as it does answer the intent of the questions at at least. The question as posed I think is a bit misleading, but also I'm much older now (almost 6 years), so thanks for the contribution, I guess we can finally mark this as done :)

Answer (score 2):

(This is a very old question, but I had the same issue and couldn't find an answer. The previous solution by hugh-allan is, as indicated in the Edit note, producing an incorrect legend.)

The settings of the scale should really be in the `scale_alpha*` parameter. That's where you manage this. The `geoms` are used for adding the data or setting a style for all points, not tuning a specific scale (otherwise, it would need to be inside the `aes()` mapping).

To be clear, there are two options in current versions of ggplot2 (using version 3.3.5):

```
tibble(x = 1:10, y = 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, alpha = x) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  scale_alpha(trans = reverse_trans())
```

or, probably more in line with current ggplot documentation:

```
  scale_alpha(range = c(1, 0.1))
```

i.e., reversing the range of the alpha scale (the default is `range = c(1, 0.1)`).